# All paths in directed tree graph from root to leaves in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

Given is a tree:

```
library(igraph)

# setup graph
g= graph.formula(A -+ B,
                 A -+ C,
                 B -+ C,
                 B -+ D,
                 B -+ E
)
plot(g, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root="A"))
```

[image]

Vertex `"A"` is the root of the tree, while vertices `"C", "D", "E"` are considered as terminal leaves.

**Problem:**

The task is to find all paths between root and leaves. I fail with following code, as it only provides the shortest paths:

```
# find root and leaves
leaves= which(degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "out")==0, useNames = T)
root= which(degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "in")==0, useNames = T)

# find all paths
paths= lapply(root, function(x) get.all.shortest.paths(g, from = x, to = leaves, mode = "out")$res)
named_paths= lapply(unlist(paths, recursive=FALSE), function(x) V(g)[x])
named_paths
```

Output:

```
$A1
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "C"

$A2
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "B" "D"

$A3
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "B" "E"
```

**Question:**

How can I find all paths including the vertex sequence: `"A" "B" "C"`?

My understanding is, that the missing sequence `"A" "B" "C"` is not provided by `get.all.shortest.paths()` as the path from `"A"` to `"C"` via the vertex sequence: `"A" "C"` (which is found in list element `$A1`) is shorter. So `igraph` works properly.
**Nevertheless I am looking for a code solution to get all paths from the root to all leaves in form of a `R list`.**

Comment:

I am aware that for large trees the algorithm covering all combinations might become expensive, but my real application is relatively small.

Comment: Try `all_simple_paths`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Gabor's comment:

```
all_simple_paths(g, from = root, to = leaves)
```

yields:

```
[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C

[[2]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B D

[[3]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B E

[[4]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named:
[1] A C
```